# How to update the app from app store if new app version is available?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, ios7

What I am trying to do is when you open the app, app will query the app store to check if your current version is lower than the one in app store. If yes, the app will direct user to app store to ***upgrade*** it.

The current version of the app on app store  is 1.5.4. What I am doing is to go to xcode and change the version of the app to 1.5.3 in xcode5 and then try to run the app again. Now I can detect a new version of the app like below :
[image]

Like I said, user will be direct to app store to update the app. However, on the app store, the page shows `Free` not `Update` one.

How can we direct user to update the app if there is a newer version from app store.
The url I am trying is

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id
```

and I also try this 
`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=`,

but app store displays a blank page.

Comment: iOS 7 will auto-update apps if user wants it, why ask user again?

Comment: in our situation, if user does not want to update, the app will crash because we are changing and modify server side. That is why we would like user to update right away whenever there is a new revision on app store.

Comment: Then do the version check with your server

Comment: You're still better with some transition period where you support different API versions. E.g. app can appear in the stores of different countries at different times, also users might not be able to download it right away, being on cellular. Also they might like your app and leave it open for several days.

Comment: @DanF : what is the difference when do version check with server ?

Comment: Because that is something you're completely in control of, and already have a system in place to communicate with, rather than trying to figure out how to see what version is on the app store.  Also if you were to make an update that doesn't change the server communication then users will nor necessarily have to update in order to continue using the application